# How to run Adobe illustrator Cs4 in Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: adobe

first I apologize for asking a question like this, I have no interest in Inkscape, I've Tried installing Adobe master collection in ubuntu but it failed, Some people said to use Virtual box and try it but it is too slow- I tried it.Do i need to install any other package with wine or something

Comment: i heard that installing adobe apps in ubuntu is illegal :)

Comment: Is it, sad. i have installed Adobe CS3 master collection on windows. if there is a way to just run it by doing some tricks(Registry or something) it will be useful, Please help, I need to get off from windows permanently and take a ride with ubuntu!

Comment: @tachyons : Windows licensing is quite complex. Using Wine without additions is legal. When you use Winetricks, you are warned of the components that requires a Windows License. Copying a dll from windows to Linux is more complex but generally only need a Windows License. Afterwards there is legal stuff and there is support stuff in the end user license ... and it is logic that adobe can try to protect himself from supporting over an unsupported platform. (like the example of prohibiting the cat inside a microwave oven written on a microwave oven manual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The natural answer would be : use wine (witch has just released the 1.4 version)

However it seems that cs illustrator versions are garbage from an old test (more than a year).

What I would recommend you is try to give a go to wine despite of the garbage status.

Wine is a sort of framework that makes windows application compatible with Linux.

For starting with wine look over here : http://www.winehq.org/download/

As extra help try to follow the download instruction of the link abobe and follow the instructions from point 20 to the end of this link : http://www.sucka.net/2009/08/installing-adobe-cs4-in-wine/

In case that wine fails you, please fill a bug here : http://bugs.winehq.org/ the help that you can give will help this project to fix the bugs with your app and then help you afterwards by having a version that supports it.

In the case of wine can't run Illustrator then there is this option that will work 100% sure :

- Install VirtualBox
- Install a Windows as a guest under VirtualBox (some windows licences allow to create a windows machine guest)
- Install Adobe Illustrator CS4 under your new VM

Virtualbox download : https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
Just run virtualbox, do new virtual machine and just answer the questions and put the windows cd into your computer and let's go ... it's quite straightforward

Answer (score 4):

try **play on linux**. link -> http://www.playonlinux.com/en

This application uses **wine** to create a platform for windows applications, But the specialty in this application is it installs other necessary addons it self to run the specific application.(such as c++ pack , direct x, .net frame work , etc) . So you will not have to find answers to questions such as

> Do i need to install any other package with wine or something?

Comment: PlayOnLinux can also be installed through the Ubuntu Software Centre, just by searching for "Play on linux".

Comment: It doesn't work on both wine or playonlinux, it even does not start the installer

Comment: Wine states AI CS4 as garbage, probably it will not run.

Answer (score 2):

Choices

Codeweaver: Does not Work, CS5 does not either.

http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/company/?company_id=2

WINE : CS4 has a "garbage" rating with this exception on 10.04

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14514&iTestingId=39828

Play on Linux : Has a mediocre rating 3.5 of 5 stars dates to 2009

http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/?script=595

Oracle [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) with Windows XP or Windows 7

Answer (score 1):

Crossover by CodeWeavers may work - it is Wine-based, but sometimes offers good compatibility with adobe, ms office, etc.